# Error : The current directory is reserved for MATLAB files

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-deployment

I am trying to run my simulink file it was working fine at the university but now when i copied those files to my own computer , I am getting the following error

[image]

and pwd command gives me the same library

> > pwd

ans =

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\MATLAB_WORK\TU4\tu4
I cannot figure out whats wrong

Comment: it seems that you are trying to save items into the Matlab reserved directory, don't do it, move out to your desktop or some other drive

Comment: I was running simulink files in the same directory but never faced such an error before , i changed my location to another disk drive and it works now , thanks alot

Comment: It depends on the model. Some models might need to generate temporary files for running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put your MATLAB_WORK directory under MATLAB's binary directory.  Put in your Documents area under your user account.  There are a few reasons for this:

1. If you're using backups, your user account is backed up.  Program files are not.
2. MATLAB pre-parses its own toolbox files for faster startup.  But this means that it many cases it doesn't detect changes in M-files in its own toolboxes.
3. MATLAB is telling you to

Comment: thanks , i changed the library to some other disk drive and it worked

Comment: please accept the answer if you think it is correct and/or have resolved your needs